# gcc/clang different behavior on linux and macOS for implicit function declarations : warning or error

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, clang

On Ubuntu 21.04 I get a warning:

```
test.c: In function ‘foo’:
test.c:3:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘bar’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    3 |   int x = bar();
      |           ^~~
```

whereas on macOS Big Sur 11.2 I get an error:

```
test.c:3:11: error: implicit declaration of function 'bar' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  int x = bar();
          ^
1 error generated.
```

when compiling this C source file (**test.c**)

```
int foo()
{
  int x = bar();
  return x;
}
```

I use the same compiler options on both Linux and macOS:

```
$ gcc -c test.c -o test.o
```

Compiler versions:

- Linux:

  ```
  $ gcc --version
  gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0
  Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
  warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
  ```
- macOS

  ```
  $ gcc --version
  Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
  Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
  Thread model: posix
  InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
  ```

Why is there a difference in behavior? How can I turn the macOS error into a warning?

Comment: Because there is `-Werror,` and there is not.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, is there a way to turn it off on the command line for macOS?

Comment: I think I found how to disable it: Add the compiler flag `-Wno-implicit-function-declaration`

Comment: Or `-Wno-error`. (But as for why on macos this option is there by default, I do not know.)

Comment: @KamilCuk Strangely `-Wno-error` has no effect, I still get the same error message. But `-Wno-implicit-function-declaration` works

Comment: An implicit function declaration is a bug. Fix the bug, don't fiddle with the flags.

Comment: @n.m. Aborting with an error rather than just issuing a warning, as it's been traditionally done, is where the bug is--i.e., in clang. In some contexts (like a quick compiler-explorer experiment) I actually *do* want to be sloppy and a compiler forcing me to write way more than necessary *bugs* me way more than me possibly escaping punishment for a temporary quick-and-dirty reliance on a deprecated (yet still well-defined) C feature.

Comment: @PSkocik In C99 and forward this feature is not deprecated, it is *removed*. C99 says so right in the foreword.